# Got error while parsing data : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, d3.js

I am using following code to read and parse data , I am working on creating graphs using d3.js and dc.js

```
function makeGraphs(error, apiData) {

    //Start Transformations
    var dataSet = apiData;

    var dateFormat = d3.time.format("%m/%d/%Y");
    console.log(dateFormat);

    dataSet.forEach(function(d) {

    console.log(d.DateOfStop);
    console.log("before");
    d.DateOfStop = dateFormat.parse(d.DateOfStop);
    console.log("after");
    console.log(d.DateOfStop);
    //d.DateOfStop.setDate(1);
});
```

I noticed that it does not throw any error when I limit the data to less than 15 records, but more than 15 records I got following error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

I did check the database undefined data for the field "DateOfStop", but the data is stored fine ,I am using mongo DB.

Can anyone look into this.

Thanks.

Comment: So on the 16th record does `console.log(d.DateOfStop);` log anything?

Comment: d3.js:2512 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined . I already looked at my data stored using mongo db. "DateofStop" field is stored as string. I am not sure why its not parsing

Comment: I found the error , it is in my database, I have a record at 19th row where only one column with value is there , rest of the columns are empty. even object_id created by mongo db is empty, I am not sure how to delete row where there is no object_id. can any one suggest. Thanks